# How can I get core dump info which is happened while compiling

Tags: g++, ld

I encountered a core dump when compiling a linux project.
the outpu/log is belows:
collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 6 [Aborted], core dumped
*** Error in `/opt/toolchain/arm-2014.11//arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld': corrupted double-linked list: 0x000000004c026460 ***
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [build_target] Error 1

there is no backtrace info,and i want to know how can i get backrece info?

Comment: I recommend that you **[edit]** this to include a complete dscription of all steps leading up to that message, including everything you did and more of the output that came before that. If you're following instructions from any particular guide, then please *also* include a link to that. It *might* be possible for this to be answered without that information, but I think this is far more likely to be answered if you include it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.I'm new of building linux project, and I want to know if there is a option of   g++ to print backtrace information.I compiled with option: -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions -funswitch-loops -fgcse-after-reload -funwind-tables  -fno-peephole2  -ftree-slp-vectorize -fpredictive-commoning